# I would like single.php to act just like index.php

Tags: functions, single

I'm creating a WordPress theme for my portfolio and I would like to my single.php file to act just like the index.php. I need the single.php to show the entire loop but if I access single post's page it only shows the specific post not the full list of posts.

I'm using a one page design and I have to use i.e `<?php echo($post->post_name) ?>` on page load in order to load some AJAX and have some deeplinking, etc.

If I delete the single.php it also only shows the specific post not the full list of posts when using a http://www.example.com/postname URL. Deleting functions.php doesn't change anything about it.

Here is a simplified version of the index.php/single.php loop:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (has_post_format( 'image' )) { ?>
<?php } else if (has_post_format('chat')) { ?>
<?php } else if (has_post_format('gallery')) { ?>
<?php } else if (has_post_format('video')) { ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: If you don't have a `single.php`, it (usually) does use `index.php`. Could you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want the url for every post to instead show the main blog feed.

Comment: Also, you have an unclosed bracket in that code (closing the `else` statement). Not sure if that's just an oversight in pasting the code...

Comment: Yup forgot to paste the <?php } ?> ;-) thanks ...

Comment: It does use index.php but only shows the post of the that single post url. Not the all the posts. Just did the test with the Twenty Twelve theme and it does the same after renaming it's single.php file.

Comment: Correct. That is the expected behavior. This is because the loop only has the one post to loop through.

Comment: OK but what I need is single.php to show all the posts if possible. Because I need the data of single.php but still want to show all the posts.

Comment: There is no "data of single.php". It is the same data used by the Loop on (usually) `index.php`. As already pointed out, it sounds like you are putting a blog index at every single post URL. That doesn't make sense. Can you explain why you want to do this? What is the point? What does the result look like?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I'm using a single page design and I to use the <?php echo($post->post_name) ?> on page load in order to load some AJAX and have some deeplinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a [secondary loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops) using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)to get all posts;

the links should have enough examples to get you started.